# Switch SQL result columns to rows and include a summary row beneath

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'd like the below columns to populate in the place of rows and then include a summary row beneath it:

```
table1
ID     NAME    Value   Group
001    Bob     100     A
002    Don     200     A
003    Fay     300     B
```

Below is an example of the desired output:

```
GROUP       NO    SUM    
Group A     2     300
Group B     1     300    
Total       3     600
```

Comment: Did you try `With ROLLUP`?

Comment: ^ Documentation can be found here: [Summarizing Data Using `ROLLUP`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189305(v=sql.90).aspx)

Comment: @WEI_DBA wow, no. I never used "WITH ROLLUP" before - that was totally a simple way to do it, thanks!

Comment: @Santi thanks for the documentation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select coalesce('Group '+ [group], 'Total') [Group], count([group]) No, sum(value) SUM
from table1
group by [group] with rollup
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/655f4/3

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([ID] varchar(50),[NAME] varchar(50),[Value] int,[Group] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('001','Bob',100,'A')
,('002','Don',200,'A')
,('003','Fay',300,'B')

Select [Group] = IsNull('Group '+[Group],'Total')
      ,[No]    = count(*)
      ,[Sum]   = sum(Value)
 From @YourTable
 Group By rollup([Group])
```

Returns

```
Group   No  Sum
Group A 2   300
Group B 1   300
Total   3   600
```